# Why use forward slash '/' instead of backward slash '\' in relative paths in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, image, relative-path, src

In the little JavaScript I wrote, the 'src' attribute of 'img' element accepted and displayed the image only if I changed '\' to '/' in the relative path of the image.

Why is it so?

```
<html>
  <body>

   <img id="image" src="F:\wallpapers\other\black-and-white-lion-chess-hd-531078.jpg">
   //why did '\' work here?

   <script>

    document.getElementById("image").src="F:/wallpapers/other/clouds_nature_skyscapes.jpg";
    //why didn't '\' work here? Why did I have to use '/' ?
  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You probably want ```file://``` URLs; they're better supported, and there's an RFC I can point to that defines their syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A single `\` character in a Javascript string is used to "escape" the next character, e.g. `\n` is used for the newline character. See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_string.asp)

In your example, if you want to use windows path names, use `\\` as path separator, like so: `F:\\wallpapers\\other\\clouds_nature_skyscapes.jpg`

Comment: Thanks @Gereon, It worked. Now I understood the reason. The 'Special Characters' section in the above cited link by Gereon http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_string.asp explains it further.